# visual studio update 2013 1,2,3,4,5

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Just wanted to ask if the update 4 for the visual studio 2013 also includes the updates 1,2,3,4? Becuase it is the only thing available on the side, I cannot download the updates for 1,2,3 and the size is really big contains about 5. ++ gb of data.

Comment: Did you even read the description? [Description of Visual Studio 2013 Update 4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2994375) "_Visual Studio 2013 updates are cumulative releases_"

Comment: Theoretically yes, practically no.  I've seen users complain that they did not get added features.  Typescript in particular is missing when Update 2 is skipped.  But since you claim to not have any other option but skip updates, there's no point in asking about it is there?

Comment: sir / superior @hans passant, my next question if it is not cummulative, Where to download the rest? :) sorry for my question if it bothers you. My point is to look for other porta/ websites where can I download those updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the updates are cumulative. Installing Update 4 will include all the things that were added by previous updates.

[image]

Find any missing features on:

- [The Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/)
- [Web Platform Installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255386)